# C++ integer floor function

Tags: c++, math

I want to implement greatest integer function. [The "greatest integer function" is a [quite](http://www.google.com/search?q=greatest%20integer%20function) [standard name](http://books.google.com/books?q=greatest+integer+function) for what is also known as the floor function.]

```
int x = 5/3;
```

My question is with greater numbers could there be a loss of precision as 5/3 would produce a double?

EDIT: Greatest integer function is integer less than or equal to X.
Example:

```
4.5 = 4
4 = 4
3.2 = 3
3 = 3
```

What I want to know is 5/3 going to produce a double? Because if so I will have loss of precision when converting to int.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: what is greatest integer function?

Comment: Be aware that in C and C++, the `/` operator acting on integers always returns an integer result. Beyond that, I think you need to be more specific about what you want---is your function going to return the greatest integer **less tham** a given number? What type is that number going to have? If it's a `float` or `double`, you will have loss of precision regardless. If it's a home-grown type that models the **rational** numbers, you can avoid the loss of precision.

Comment: It's a function returning the *greatest* integer ever!  I believe the greatest one is 1,000,001

Comment: No sorry, I once found that 1,000,002 was the greatest !

Comment: I thought the greatest integer was 42, or maybe 4,711.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=greatest+integer+function
"Greatest integer function" is a pretty standard name, especially outside the US and especially common until a couple of decades ago.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/ ?

Comment: I guess it's short for "greatest integer less than or equal to the input."  It's easy to see why the IEEE 754 folks decided to use terms like "round toward negative infinity" instead.

Comment: why on earth do you want to do a floating-point division just to get the floor function? Just do a simple integer division. That's faster and easier than converting back and forth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will lose the fractional portion of the quotient.  So yes, with greater numbers you will have more relative precision, such as compared with `5000/3000`.

However, `5 / 3` will return an integer, not a double. To force it to divide as double, typecast the dividend as `static_cast<double>(5) / 3`.

Answer (score 5):

Integer division gives integer results, so 5 / 3 is 1 and 5 % 3 is 2 (the remainder operator).  However, this doesn't necessarily hold with negative numbers.  In the original C++ standard, -5 / 3 could be either -1 (rounding towards zero) or -2 (the floor), but -1 was recommended.  In the latest C++0B draft (which is almost certainly very close to the final standard), it is -1, so finding the floor with negative numbers is more involved.

Answer (score 3):

5/3 will always produce 1 (an integer), if you do 5.0/3 or 5/3.0 the result will be a double.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no predefined function for this purpose.
It might be necessary to use such a function, if for some reason floating-point calculations are out of question (e.g. `int64_t` has a higher precision than `double` can represent without error)

We could define this function as follows:

```
#include <cmath>

inline long
floordiv (long num, long den)
{
  if (0 < (num^den))
    return num/den;
  else
    {
      ldiv_t res = ldiv(num,den);
      return (res.rem)? res.quot-1 
                      : res.quot;
    }
}
```

The idea is to use the normal integer divison, but adjust for negative results to match the behaviour of the `double floor(double)` function. The point is to truncate always towards the next lower integer, irrespective of the position of the zero point. This can be very important if the intention is to create even sized intervals.

Timing measurements show that this function here only creates a small overhead compared with the built-in `/` operator, but of course the floating point based `floor` function is significantly faster....

Answer (score -1):

Since in C and C++, as others have said, / is integer division, it will return an int. in particular, it will return the floor of the double answer... (C and C++ always truncate) So, basically 5/3 is exactly what you want.

It may get a little weird in negatives as -5/3 => -2 which may or may not be what you want...

Comment: It is **not** true that integer division returns the floor!

The (often overlooked) key point is how *negative* numbers are treated. Here -9 / 4 == -2 but floor(-9.0/4) == -3.0

Comment: actually -5/3 gives -1 which is not floor.

Comment: Not in old fashioned c. In c (-5)/3 =-2. Maybe this has changed in the last 20 years...